# Continuous function maps boundary to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is regards to an old question:

[Image of a boundary under a continuous function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162919/image-of-a-boundary-under-a-continuous-function)

Given a continuous function, bijective on an open bounded set... prove the function maps the boundary of the set to itself.

I don't understand the solution. Specifically this:

"By bijectivity & continuity, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)\cap \Omega$ is compactly contained in $\Omega$. Yet $f(x_n)\in U$ for all large $n$, a contradiction."

Comment: The map is proper since it is bijective on itself.

Comment: A continuous bijection of a set to itself is a proper map? Can you direct me to a proof of this.

Comment: The pre-image of a compact set is itself, which is compact.

Comment: I see now thanks.

Comment: pre-image of a compact set is not itself  it is only a bijection not identity